# Why left Right scroll isn't working on Ubuntu 17

Tags: 17.10, gestures

I've upgraded my laptop to ubuntu 17.10 from version 16.x and now i'm not able to use left-right scroll using fingers gestures on touchpad.

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at the [release notes](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ArtfulAardvark/ReleaseNotes)?

> Mouse & Touchpad settings and behavior will not work right in the Ubuntu desktop if xserver-xorg-input-synaptics is installed. Some desktop environments such as Unity require xserver-xorg-input-synaptics. (1686081)

After removing `xorg-input-synaptics` everything should work as expected.

That said, it only works for me until the first suspend, after that it stops working again.